# Application that counts hours / minutes and sends them to database

Tags: mysql, web, web-applications, workflow

I want to count how much time I spent developing my game, I think that the best option out there is to make an easy web application. What technology should I use? The easiest option is to create a web app, connect it to my MySQL database and count hours & minutes when I toggle a button. Are there any premade applications that do just that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.toggl.com/ is exactly what you intend to do. Though your approach does require one to manually start/stop the timer.

There are applications that "track" your time in automated way; this they do mostly by tracking how much time you spend on computer and in which app. The time spent in/on app(s) may be roughly correlated to time spent on development. e.g. time spent on Visual Studio + SQL etc.